Rjsf Object Collapse Functionality using CustomObjectTemplate
I want to have a dropdown for some of objects in the form which are not necessarily shown to the user , so i have written a template called CollapsibleObjectTemplate,
the issue is it is getting applied to every object in the schema
Every object in the schema is now having a dropdown , how to restrict it to only the objects I want ??
example in here every object is getting drop down
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CollapsibleObjectTemplate: React.FC<any> = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const toggleSection = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: "16px" }}>
      <div
        onClick={toggleSection}
      >
        <span>{props.title || "Advanced Settings"}</span>
        <span>{isOpen ? "▲" : "▼"}</span>
      </div>

      {isOpen && (
        <div>
          {props.properties.map((element: any) => (
            <div key={element.name} style={{ marginBottom: "12px" }}>
              {element.content}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CollapsibleObjectTemplate;


Form Usage :
<Form
 schema={resourceSchema}
 uiSchema={uiSchema}
 formData={formData}
 onChange={({ formData }) => setFormData(formData)}
 onSubmit={handleSubmit}
 validator={validator}
 templates={{ ObjectFieldTemplate : CollapsibleObjectTemplate }}
>

How to use the template on my needs is my using , I think by default every object is getting this
